# Agora Cloud Recording Returns Code 435, but works fine when token/cname generated dynamically

Tags: flutter, agora.io

I am following Cloud Recording APIs by Agora thoroughly. I am connecting to the server, generating token from Agora SDK, acquire resource ID, start recording and end recording calls.

Start Recording returns status code 200 with sid and resource Id.

But, when I stop the call, it returns the code "435". It means there was no user in the call. But I have connected to the call.

When I do the same using cname and token generated from the "Create temp token" on agora website, it works fine and recording is stored.

So is the issue in token generation? Because I am using Agora SDK for the same and passing parameters rightly...

> public String getPublisherRTCToken(String sid) {

```
    RtcTokenBuilder token = new RtcTokenBuilder();
    int expireTime = 3600;
    String strtoken = token.buildTokenWithUid(
            agoraAppId,
            agoraCertificate,
            sid,
            0,
            RtcTokenBuilder.Role.Role_Publisher,
            (int) (System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000 + expireTime));
    logger.debug("uid {} Token {}", uid, strtoken);
    return strtoken;
}
```

Can someone please help me with this!

Comment: which library are you using to generate the tokens?

Comment: Hello @Hermes  did you find any solution to this issue, I am having the same issue, I don't know about the temp token but when I am generating token and then trying to do cloud recording but the return code is always 435.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you are using the same channel name which you used to create token and joining video call while making request for acquiring resource and start recording.

Comment: Yes, I am using the same channel name but still it does not work it always returns the 435 code.